# How to sum the information at two consecutive positions in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with position,k, y. For example

```
pos k y
123 0.7 0.5
124 0.4 0.1
125 0.3 0.2
126 0.4 0.1
128 0.3 0.6
130 0.4 0.9
131 0.3 0.2
```

i would like to sum the information at k and y like

```
123 1.1 0.6
125 0.7 0.3
128 0.3 0.6
130 0.7 1.1
```

so the output has only the first positions and the sum of value the first and its immediate consecutive number which follows it.

I tried grouping by pandas

```
for k,g in df.groupby(df['pos'] - np.arange(df.shape[0])):
   u=g.ix[0:,2:].sum()
```

but its groups all the consecutive numbers which I dont want

ALSO I NEED SOMETHING FAST AS I HAVE 2611774 ROW IN MY DATAFILE

Comment: Why do you have 130 in your resulted `df`? Should it be `131`?

Comment: No I just want to sum 130 and 131 k and y coulmn informations respectively and then assign it to 130 pos

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( columns=['pos','k','y'])
cf = pd.DataFrame( columns=['pos','k','y'])
df['pos']=123, 124,125,126,128,130,131
df['k']=.7,.4,.3,.4,.3,.4,.3
df['y']=.5,.1,.2,.1,.6,.9,.2
row=0
while 1:
    if row+1<len(df):
        if(df.loc[row]['pos']+1==df.loc[row+1]['pos']):
            cf.loc[row]= df.loc[row]+df.loc[row+1]
            cf.loc[row]['pos']=df.loc[row]['pos']
            row=row+2
        else:
            cf.loc[row]= df.loc[row]
            row=row+1
    else:
        break
print cf
```

Comment: Thanks ankit but I want to use something fast while loop is really slow !!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is faster than a loop, but it won't sum positions 123 and 124 and then 130 and 131 as I think you expect, because it sums odd positions with its consecutive like 129 and 130, 131 and 132...

```
df = df.set_index('pos')
df_odd = df.loc[df.index.values % 2 == 1]
df_even = df.loc[df.index.values % 2 == 0]
df_even = df_even.set_index(df_even.index.values - 1)
df_odd.add(df_even, fill_value = 0)
```

Result:

```
pos k   y
123 1.1 0.6
125 0.7 0.3
127 0.3 0.6
129 0.4 0.9
131 0.3 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used pandas before, but if you get the chance to use the data as a list then this should work.

```
def SumNext(L):
  N = xrange(len(L)-1)
  Output = [L[i]+L[i+1] for i in N]
  return Output
```

This function will give you a summation of consecutive elements if you input a list.

A=[1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
SumNext(A) => [2,3,5,8,13]

then you just have to read out the values to wherever you like, it is much faster to do things in lists (as opposed to while loops) when you get lots of elements.

then you will just need to figure out the implementation of passing the output back to your data frame.